# Compile SASS directory into multiple files

Tags: css, sass

**Q.** *How do I / is it possible to split my `/SCSS` directory into multiple output `.css` files?*

I have a part of the application `/admin` that I don't want to serve to the standard user for performances reasons. Also, there are some standalone landing pages that are not part of the 'main' site, so could do with their own bundle.

**Example SCSS structure:**

```
/scss
  - partials
  - modules
```

**Compile into:**

```
main.css
admin.css
landing.css
```

**Note:** I'm using webpack

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually possible with SASS? Although I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Please try the ExtractTextPlugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Comment: @ThiagoCoelho great thank you! Add this as an answer below and I'll accept.